# Text box size in Flash

Tags: flash, text, field

Is there a way to get the size of a dynamic text box at run time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

of course,
either with its **textWidth**/**textHeight** properties for its visible size or by its **width**/**height** properties for the bounding box size.